# Decode an image file path into image and set it to the layout in android

Tags: java, android

Iam retreiving the file path related to particular image,but the path is not decoded.

Here is my code,

```
 BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 bmpFactoryOptions.inScaled = false;
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" +mSignature.file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mSignature.file.getPath(), bmpFactoryOptions);
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + bitmap, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 ivSignature.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I am getting the path but not the image is set in the layout...Solve the problem.

Comment: Solve the problem? Can you be nicer?

Comment: use image loader check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Comment: your image is in base64??

Comment: is the image on the SD card? did you add android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to your manifest?

Comment: what is the format of image you want to retrieve?

Comment: png format.Even if it is  the format  jpg  no result...

Answer (score 0):

I think you code is right, But haven't you add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` when you want read SDCard?

Comment: Have you try to run in the other androidphone?